# Google sheets previous 6 months data query

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

so I have this query that pulls all the data from the previous month but I would like it to pull the previous 6 months

```
=query(Insiders!A4:L,"Select * where month(C)=month(now())-1",1)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking the current month as July, if you want to display results where the date in Col C is in Jan 2021 to June 2021 inclusive, then try this:

```
=arrayformula(query(Insiders!A4:L,"Select * where C>= date '"&text(eomonth(today(),-7)+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and C< date '"&text(eomonth(today(),-1)+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' ",1))
```

Currently (at 10/7/2021), `text(eomonth(today(),-7)+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")` = 2021-01-01

`text(eomonth(today(),-1)+1,"yyyy-mm-dd")` = 2021-07-01

These are the two date search ranges.

You can alter the `eomonth()` function parameters `-7` and `-1` to move the months into a different period.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the EDATE function in Google sheets in combination with EOMONTH function to get your answer. Something like this:

EDATE(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,-5) - This will give you the first date of the n-6th month and then you can sum that till the last date of the current month so:

SUMIFS('Insiders'!A4:L,*Date Range*,">="EDATE(EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)+1,-5 & "<="TODAY()

Make sure your *Date Range* is in the date format and not in the month format

Hope this helps

Answer (score -1):

try:

```
=QUERY(Insiders!A4:L, "where month(C)+1="&MONTH(TODAY()), 1)
```

Comment: @Peter can you copy/share a sample of your sheet?